# Ubuntu dpkg, non interactive installation

Tags: ubuntu, bash, installation, apt, dpkg

I am trying to install a bunch of .deb files without having to interact with them. MySQL Server for example will prompt for an interactive menu to enter an administrative password upon the dpkg's configuration.

I have tried.

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && export DEBIAN_PRIORITY=critical && sudo /usr/bin/dpkg -i ./files/*
```

I am aware that I can just extract the files without configuration. I am trying to create a bash script to deploy a server pre-configured of default installation of Apache, php, mySQL etc. However, this "interactive installation" is causing issues.

Any ideas on how to disable it? or a work around?

Thanks

Comment: What will you do about the MySQL server's root password without answering the question?

Comment: Use mysqladmin to configure the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable prompts while installing a Debian package](http://serverfault.com/questions/210948/disable-prompts-while-installing-a-debian-package)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are on the right track. You definitely want to use `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`. For critical questions that cannot be ignored, you will want to preseed the `debconf` database with the necessary answers. The [`debconf` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man7/debconf.7.html) has all the details about how to accomplish that.

Comment: needed to "su -" and use "export" as root.

Comment: sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y package_you_want

Answer (score 7):

For general noninteractive frontend, you may try:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure debconf -f noninteractive -p critical
```

To configure MySQL credentials, you may use [server configuration file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-default-configuration-file.html) (e.g. `~/.my.cnf`), like:

```
[client]
user=root
password=root
```

To select some specific selections, use `debconf-set-selections`, e.g.:

```
echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$ pkgadd SOMEpkg << MYINPUT

y

some text

/usr/local

n

password

MYINPUT
```

I had to place blnk lines between the lines above or it formatted as one long line.
In any case you can use the "script" command to save your input during complex installs, and then modify the output into a script to automate it for subsequent installations (`man script`).