# Disable prompts while installing a Debian package

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, repository, packages

How can i disable totally the prompts that appear while installing a Debian package, i've used all the options that i've found but there are some packages that are still prompting.

I'm using this command:

```
apt-get -y --allow-unauthenticated --force-yes -o DPkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confdef" install x11-common
```

Why the x11-common package is still prompting? how can i get rid of these prompts?

Thanks in advance

--Victor

Edit: just to clarify, the prompts are not "yes/no" prompts, are open questions in a coloured screen (typical two color screen) but i want to set the default option of these questions

Answer (score 44):

Select a new front end by setting your env.

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install x11-common
```

I use this all the time in automating package installation with `cfengine`.

Comment: +1 This is the right answer

Comment: In some strange cases such as when you need to use this inside chroot non interactively you can use `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  sudo -E chroot . echo "something"`

Answer (score 8):

Not having manually install x11-common, I am not sure what questions you are being asked.  But if they are coming from debconf, then you should be able to pre-answer the questions with `debconf-set-selections`.

Comment: This is the solution, thanks. I've get the properties with debconf-get-selections and set them previously with the debconf-set-selections and no more prompts appeared

Comment: Even with selections set some packages may still ask questions depending on the priority. But I do recommend setting selections where possible. Setting the frontend to `noninteractive` is the magic "don't ask me anything no matter what" flag.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `dpkg-reconfigure debconf` and tell it to "Ignore questions with a priority less than: Critical".

This doesn't get you out of answering critical questions.

Answer (score 2):

To disable the prompts globally for reconfiguring all packages with `debconf`, just comment out the second line from `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` file.

Or if you're provisioning VM, add these commands to your provision script:

```
sudo ex +"%s@DPkg@//DPkg" -cwq /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf
sudo dpkg-reconfigure debconf -f noninteractive -p critical
```

---

You may also try the same way how Travis CI does it:

```
sudo -E apt-get -yq --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends --force-yes install some_package
```

---

For some other packages, like `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` (which is dependent on `language-pack-en`), the above seems to not work, so try:

```
echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get install -y language-pack-en
```

Comment: `--force-yes` is a VERY scary and not recommended way to blast through prompts. Don't be surprised if you end up with a broken and possibly irrecoverable system someday.