# How to setup phpmyadmin without prompts in one line?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

i'd like to setup phpmyadmin in Ubuntu without asking for parameters in prompts, i don't know if there's a way to pass these parameters in the command:
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
and give the options like the server type "apache2" and mysql admin password.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

phpmyadmin appears to be using debconf for the configuration of the main package.  Which means the standard pre-seeding method applies.

See:

- [Disable prompts while installing a Debian package](https://serverfault.com/questions/210948/disable-prompts-while-installing-a-debian-package)
- http://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed

Also, if you set the installer to non-interactive configuration (`DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install`), you can simply script or manually update the configuration files after the package has been installed.